# Is "harpvox" an existing musical instrument?

Tags: instruments

My digital piano has a "harpvox" voice setting that sounds rather interesting with broad echo and low overtones feeling even for the the middle or high notes. Is it a real instrument or an invention of the manufacturer? I cannot Google anything reasonable about "harpvox".

Comment: Any chance you could post a sample?!

Comment: My guess is that the sound designers took the words *harp* and *vox* (which means voice) and stuck them together to describe a synthesized, original sound.

Comment: Interesting: "harp/vox" is a sound name available on *lots* of digital keyboards, but not with any specific definition.  So it's almost certainly a synthesized effect that's become semistandard despite not having a pedigree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Kevin" has made a correct guess.

No. ;-)

Comment: Can you add a little more to this answer?

Comment: It pretty much does provide an answer to the question. Is it an existing instrument? No.

Comment: Something with the reference to this sound, how it has been designed and that is for sure computer generated, would be better. However as of having nothing else, I accept this. Probable the answer is really no.